# Error in Function For UIBarButton for UIPopOverController - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a button called as `Sync`. On clicking on it, I need to display a popOverController which displays a few items in `UITableView`. I have used the following lines of code in `.m` file to declare the `UIButton` in `ViewWillAppear` function :

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sync"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(syncAction)] ;
```

The code for syncAction is :

```
- (void)syncAction:(id)sender{


Sync = [[SyncTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];


Sync.syncDelegate = self;
self.SyncTableViewPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                                   initWithContentViewController:Sync];               

[self.SyncTableViewPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender 
                                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];


}
```

But, however, on running the application I am getting the following error ::

```
[splitViewXXXXViewController syncAction]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b70660

2012-07-02 15:35:59.549 splitView[895:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[splitViewXXXXViewController syncAction]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b70660'
```

I am unable to sort it out. Can someone help me to sort it out ?? Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the *@selector(syncAction:)*

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sync"
                                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                          target:self
                                                          action:@selector(syncAction:)] ;
```

This will resolve you issue

Comment: yes .. it resolved the issue. Thanks a lot. I spent nearly two hours to figure out the error. :-/ It was just a `colon.

Answer (score 2):

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sync"
                                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                          target:self
                                                          action:@selector(syncAction:)] ;
```

make sure your **self** (splitViewXXXXViewController ) here has a

```
- (void)syncAction:(id)sender;
```

declared method in its header, and also

```
action:@selector(syncAction:)]
```

do not forget to add semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the additional colon ':' when calling your selector.